# Return Blob Image as Json Response in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I am trying to write an API with the image stored in Database as blob I am getting no response as JSON but getting a result as standard object or array.[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcjhO.png)

```
{
        $menu_cat_data = [];
        $main_categories = DB::table('categories')->select('categories.id as menu_category_id', 'categories.name as menu_category_name', 
                'categories.image as menu_category_image')
                ->join('products', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.CATEGORY')
                ->where('categories.SITEGUID', '=', $id)
                ->distinct()
                ->get();

        if (count($main_categories) > 0) {
            $cnt = 0;
            $menu_cat_data = [];

            foreach ($main_categories as $main_categorys) {
            $main_categorys['menu_category_image'];
                $menu_cat_data['menu'][$main_categorys-   >menu_category_id] = (array) $main_categorys;
                $products = DB::table('products')->select('products.id as menu_item_id', 'products.name as menu_item_name', 
                        'products.PRICESELL as rate', 'products.image as menu_product_image')
                        ->where('products.SITEGUID', '=', $id)
                        ->where('products.category', '=', $main_categorys->menu_category_id)
                        ->join('categories', 'products.category', '=', 'categories.id')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->get();
                if (count($products) > 0) {
                    foreach ($products as $product) {
                        $menu_cat_data['menu'][$main_categorys->menu_category_id]['items'][$product->menu_item_id] = (array) $product;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $response = json_encode($menu_cat_data);
        print_r($response);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: I think the best way to go is base64-encoding.

Comment: Hi, Thomas how to form base64-encoding in iterating array please help updated the code